# Can I avoid a double-API call with NextJS' getServerSideProps?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm tinkering with NextJS' `getServerSideProps`. I see that when I request a page from scratch, I receive the fully hydrated content. Then when I navigate to a new page, an API call is made, which receives some JSON data that is used to re-populate the page.

What I don't like is that the new API call is actually making two calls. For example my `getServerSideProps` has an `axios.get()` call. So on that click to the new page, I'm getting:

1. a call to something like `example.com/_next/data/1231234/....`
2. that call, behind the scenes, must be running my `getServerSideProps()` with its `axios.get()` to retrieve the new JSON data.

So is there a way to avoid the double-API call? I'd prefer that after the first page load, clicks to new pages would just skip to step two.

On a non-NextJS app I'd have something like a `useEffect()` that ran on page load, but obviously then the first run of the page would not return the full content, and for search-engine purposes I'd like to return the full content. I've seen some lectures where Google says they do run javascript and see the full content, but might as well be on the safe side for all other engines.

Answer (score 1):

So, the goal is to determine ways of getting props for:

- the initial (direct) page request,
- in-app navigation request

To solve this we have two options. And unfortunately, both of them are not perfect.

**First option:**

Check if the request has header `x-nextjs-data`. NextJS adds this header for fetching data from `getServerSideProps`:

```
export const isInitialPageRequest = (req: GsspRequest) => {
  return !req.headers['x-nextjs-data'];
}

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context: GetServerSidePropsContext) => {

  if (isInitialPageRequest(context.req)) {
    // this code runs only on the initial request, on the server side
  }

  return {
    props: {
      // props
    }
  }
}
```

In this case, the request to /_next/data/development/xxx.json?...' is still executed every time. But at least you can control behavior depending on the case (and avoid redundant API calls for example).

**Second option:**

Use `getInitialProps` and check if property context.req is defined or not. You already mentioned it in the comments, just added it as an answer option with an example:

```
page.getInitialProps = async (context: NextPageContext) => {
      if (context.req) {
        // this code runs only on the initial request, on the server side
      }
      
      return {
        // props
      }
}
```

The NextJS team is [recommending](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-initial-props) to use getServerSideProps instead

Answer (score 0):

`getServerSideProps` will always run at request time--whenever you hit the page (or possibly using prefetch, the default, of [next/link](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link)) This will result in **pre-render** of the page using the data from `getServerSideProps` *Side-note: If you using next API middleware, then you can avoid the ajax call and simply import the method to run directly in `getServerSideProps`.*

It sounds like you want to fetch the data at build time and could render the page statically? If so, rather look to use [getStaticProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticprops-static-generation).

You can also avoid both and make an API call in `useEffect` if you prefer, but code will be run at the client, once the page loads, of course. `getServerSideProps` will **pre-render** the page with the data before it renders to the client.

Comment: Thanks - I actually ended up switching to `getInitialProps`, which is doing what I want - pre-render on first request, and then run in browser on subsequent requests. The NextJS team is recommending `getServerSideProps` instead, but due to how it works, I don't think it will do what I want. Switching to `getInitialProps` is giving me noticeably faster page loads. Note that my `axios.get()` in these functions is calling a different server, which is why the double-API call was bad. Hopefully they don't deprecate `getInitialProps`..